# Moving a Sprite Back and Forth in pygame

Tags: python, variables, for-loop, while-loop, pygame

I have the sprite going from on end of the screen to the other, but now I want it to go back and forth forever. Any ideas?

```
u = 1 #u is the x coordinate
if u < 430: #480 is the window siz, i want it to stop at 430
   u += 5 # Move up by 5
```

Should I add my whole code so it is easier?

Comment: Should I add my whole code so It is easier for you guys to see my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a delta variable:

```
delta = 5
u = 1
```

and have it adjusted to switch directions:

```
u += delta
if u >= 430: 
   delta = -5
elif u < 50:
   delta = 5
```

Comment: Wow! nice! I think you meant that the x < 50 is suppose to be u < 50 though